# Not able to access the $scope value in html, value set in $http.post success function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am not able to access the value of the $scope properties set on success of  $http post. I am trying to access it in index.html file. below is the code for reference, please help me in resolving it, i am new to AngularJs

```
var app = angular.module('formExample', []);
app.controller("formCtrl", ['$scope','$rootScope', '$http',    
function($scope,$rootScope, $http) {
    $scope.loginurl = 'loginsubmit.php';        
    $scope.loginFormSubmit  = function(isValid) {           
        if (isValid) {              

            $http.post($scope.loginurl, {"username": $scope.username,"password": $scope.password}).
                    success(function(data, status) {
                        $scope.status = status;
                        $scope.data = data;
                        $scope.isAdmin=data.isAdmin;
                        $scope.username=data.username;                          
                        location.href="Index.html";                         
                    })  
        }else{

              alert('Form is not valid');
        }

    }



 html form code

 <div class="row" ng-app="formExample" >
       <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
          <div class"col-md-8">&nbsp;</div>
          <div>username: {{$scope.username}} </div>
```

Comment: isn't location.href redirecting the page? That will kill the $scope.

Comment: Thanks Marco, Can you suggest me how do i retain scope so that i can access it in index.html page and display user name.

Comment: You should store the data into the `$rootScope` if you're using SPA or store it into localStorage if you're not using SPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For login and authentication I usually do the same thing Marco does (mentioned in his comment) and store in $rootScope the user information. However, that is essentially the only thing I ever use it for as it is best to avoiding polluting the rootScope with a bunch of stuff.

I set up a small playground in a jsfiddle for you shamelessly stolen from this article:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/angularjs/UVDE100914-Understanding-AngularJS-$rootScope-and-$scope.html

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/kd8v6thm/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.msg = 'World';
 $rootScope.name = 'AngularJS';
 });

 app.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.msg = 'Dot Net Tricks';
 $scope.myName = $rootScope.name;
 });
```

All other answers/comments are great. I just wanted you to have this fiddle to play around with. I have learned a lot by isolating small issues and testing them, breaking them, and fixing them in fiddles.

EDIT: There are ways to share data across controllers in Angular:

Also, to address other ways to share data between controllers without a database you can also create an auth 'factory.' Services and Factories are great ways to share data across controllers and I believe they are the actual intended way.

A good discussion of this option (and others) is here:
https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec

See updated fiddle with example of a service:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/kd8v6thm/1/

with the following added:

```
app.service("auth", [ function () {
return {
    getAuth: function () {
        var info = {
            name: "Name",
            password: "Password"
            }
        return info;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to timeout your `location.href` so that the $scope is not lost.

Before the redirect, you have several options to make your user data global to the app. You can put your user variables in a controller that affects all views (such as a controller in app.js), or put it in `$rootScope` or localStorage/sessionStorage as @Marco in the comments suggests.

Also, use `{{ username }}` instead of `{{ $scope.username }}`. The latter doesn't print anything.

Comment: `$scope` will be lost no matter what if OP does redirect. javascript has no persistence between page loads

Comment: @chakeda, can you show a fiddle of the behavior your are describing with timeout & location.href?